# Determining the outline of the shape in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I want to determine an outer circle that bounds the shape, the edges of the shape, and the circle inside the shape.

I use this code for the threshold:

```
    def adjustImage(img):
        src = adjust_gamma(img, 0.5)
        src_gray = src.copy()
        src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (5,5))
        hsv = cv.cvtColor(src_gray, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h, s, v = cv.split(hsv)
        thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(v, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 5, 3)
        return thresh
```

However, this code doesn't always work. For example, for this image the result of the code is incorrect:
[image: Ex3]

Could anyone provide me with some guidance on why this code is not working for all of these images?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try different parameters for `adaptiveThreshold()`?

Comment: @Powercoder I have tried using different parameters for adaptiveThreshold(). However, when I change the parameters, some of the images work and some of the images don't work. From what I can tell, there aren't a certain set of parameters that work for all of the images.

Comment: Attaching source images without drawn circles would make people easier to help you

Comment: Your adaptive threshold needs to be tuned for each image. Try OTSU thresholding in its place. Skip the blur and if you need to get rid of minor extraneous regions, use contour filtering on area or morphology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images you gave are some noisy and seems like they required filterring before using `adaptiveThreshold()`, something better than just blur. Maybe `cv.fastNlMeansDenoising()` is a candidate. Check the difference:

cv.blur: [image: cv2.blur result], cv.fastNlMeansDenoising: [image: cv.fastNlMeansDenoising result]

If your input images are always like this, I mean pretty solid-dihotomic, I'd recommend to use this way of thresholding instead:

```
def adjustImage(img):
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    v_avg = np.average(src_gray)
    v_max = np.max(src_gray)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(src_gray, v_avg + (v_max - v_avg) / 2, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    thresh = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5)))
    return thresh
```

Or, as @fmw42 mentioned, OTSU is even more natural solution:

```
def adjustImage(img):
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv.threshold(src_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5)))
    return thresh
```

The code you posted doesn't draw circles stright after copypaste for some reason but take a look at what we get with the function above:

[image: example1] [image: example2] [image: example3]

Comment: Why not just use OTSU thresholding?

Comment: OTSU is a fine solution too